# Error in max.item - min.item : non-numeric argument to binary operator in psych package

Tags: r

I want to analyze students' responses in Rstudio. I have an answers dataframe for 100 students and 50 questions, and a dataframe
for correct answers. I used score.multiple.choice in psych package...but due to my data I got a message "Error in max.item - min.item : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

```
Student.tf <- score.multiple.choice(key_A, sudent_all,score=FALSE)
Error in max.item - min.item : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

is it possible to hanle with this problem

```
**STUDENT ANSWER**
|id    |q1 |q2 |q3 |q4|...|q50
|1     | A |B  |C  |D |   | E
|2     | B |B  |A  |E |   | E
.
.
.
|99    | A |B  |C  |D |   |E
|100   | A |B  |C  |D |   |E

**KEY**
|id   |q1|q2| q3| q4...|q50
|1    |A | B|  C|  D   | E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few flaws in your reasoning. First, your data is of type char and the function `score.multiple.choice` requires numeric values. Second, as the name itself will select the `score.multiple.choice` vector mesh with multiple choice. The whole thing can be solved without resorting to the `psyche` package. Look below.

For starters, I simulated the relevant data.

```
library(tidyverse)

nid = 100
nq = 50

sudent_all = tibble(
 id = rep(1:nid, nq),
 nqest = rep(paste0("q", 1:nq), each = nid),
 answ = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), nid*nq, replace = TRUE)
) %>% mutate(answ = answ %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = nqest, values_from = answ)

key_A = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), nq, replace = TRUE) %>% fct_inorder()
```

output sudent_all

```
# A tibble: 100 x 51
      id q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8    q9    q10   q11   q12   q13   q14   q15   q16   q17   q18   q19   q20  
   <int> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1     1 E     A     B     A     C     E     C     E     C     E     B     D     C     E     A     D     C     C     E     E    
 2     2 B     A     E     E     A     D     A     E     B     D     C     E     D     B     A     E     E     D     B     B    
 3     3 E     D     A     B     A     A     E     A     D     C     B     D     E     E     B     D     D     E     A     A    
 4     4 B     B     B     D     B     E     B     B     C     D     D     A     E     D     E     B     E     D     E     C    
 5     5 E     C     E     E     D     A     C     E     B     B     B     A     C     A     E     A     D     A     C     E    
 6     6 B     D     A     E     E     A     D     D     C     C     C     C     A     D     E     E     E     B     A     B    
 7     7 E     A     D     E     E     D     A     C     E     D     C     C     D     E     C     C     A     C     D     E    
 8     8 B     A     E     D     D     D     D     A     A     A     E     D     D     A     A     C     E     C     C     B    
 9     9 C     B     B     E     B     B     E     A     E     E     D     A     B     D     D     E     B     C     E     D    
10    10 C     C     B     D     E     A     A     D     A     E     E     C     B     D     A     C     B     E     C     E    
# ... with 90 more rows, and 30 more variables: q21 <fct>, q22 <fct>, q23 <fct>, q24 <fct>, q25 <fct>, q26 <fct>, q27 <fct>,
#   q28 <fct>, q29 <fct>, q30 <fct>, q31 <fct>, q32 <fct>, q33 <fct>, q34 <fct>, q35 <fct>, q36 <fct>, q37 <fct>, q38 <fct>,
#   q39 <fct>, q40 <fct>, q41 <fct>, q42 <fct>, q43 <fct>, q44 <fct>, q45 <fct>, q46 <fct>, q47 <fct>, q48 <fct>, q49 <fct>,
#   q50 <fct>
```

output key_A

```
key_A
 [1] A E E B E B B E A B C B B C C E D D D C B C A E B E B C E B D B A D C E A A E B E D A A B D C C A A
Levels: A E B C D
```

Now all you need is two simple functions and one mutation.

```
fCheck = function(data, key) data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(value = value==key) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

fSumCorr = function(data) data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% pull(value) %>% sum()

sudent_all %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~fCheck(.x, key_A))) %>% 
  mutate(sumCorr = map(data, ~fSumCorr(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(sumCorr)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
# Groups:   id [100]
      id data              sumCorr
   <int> <list>              <int>
 1     1 <tibble [1 x 50]>       6
 2     2 <tibble [1 x 50]>      11
 3     3 <tibble [1 x 50]>       9
 4     4 <tibble [1 x 50]>      10
 5     5 <tibble [1 x 50]>      12
 6     6 <tibble [1 x 50]>       8
 7     7 <tibble [1 x 50]>      11
 8     8 <tibble [1 x 50]>      10
 9     9 <tibble [1 x 50]>      12
10    10 <tibble [1 x 50]>       8
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Note that using `sudent_all%>% group_by (id)%>% nest ()`, I collapse the responses for each student into a single `tibble`

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
# Groups:   id [100]
      id data             
   <int> <list>           
 1     1 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 2     2 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 3     3 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 4     4 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 5     5 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 6     6 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 7     7 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 8     8 <tibble [1 x 50]>
 9     9 <tibble [1 x 50]>
10    10 <tibble [1 x 50]>
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Such a `tibble` is easy to further modify using the `mutate` and `map` functions.

**Update 1**

I don't know anything about the psyche package. But if conversion is a problem, you can do it this way.

```
fConv = function(data, key) data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value==key, 1, 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

df = sudent_all %>% group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~fConv(.x, key_A)))


df$data[[1]]
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 50
     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8    q9   q10   q11   q12   q13   q14   q15   q16   q17   q18   q19   q20   q21
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
# ... with 29 more variables: q22 <dbl>, q23 <dbl>, q24 <dbl>, q25 <dbl>, q26 <dbl>, q27 <dbl>, q28 <dbl>, q29 <dbl>, q30 <dbl>,
#   q31 <dbl>, q32 <dbl>, q33 <dbl>, q34 <dbl>, q35 <dbl>, q36 <dbl>, q37 <dbl>, q38 <dbl>, q39 <dbl>, q40 <dbl>, q41 <dbl>,
#   q42 <dbl>, q43 <dbl>, q44 <dbl>, q45 <dbl>, q46 <dbl>, q47 <dbl>, q48 <dbl>, q49 <dbl>, q50 <dbl>
```

**Update 2**

```
df = sudent_all %>% group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~fConv(.x, key_A))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 51
# Groups:   id [100]
      id    q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8    q9   q10   q11   q12   q13
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0
 2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
 3     3     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 4     4     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 5     5     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 6     6     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 7     7     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 8     8     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
 9     9     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
10    10     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
# ... with 90 more rows, and 37 more variables: q14 <dbl>, q15 <dbl>, q16 <dbl>,
#   q17 <dbl>, q18 <dbl>, q19 <dbl>, q20 <dbl>, q21 <dbl>, q22 <dbl>, q23 <dbl>,
#   q24 <dbl>, q25 <dbl>, q26 <dbl>, q27 <dbl>, q28 <dbl>, q29 <dbl>, q30 <dbl>,
#   q31 <dbl>, q32 <dbl>, q33 <dbl>, q34 <dbl>, q35 <dbl>, q36 <dbl>, q37 <dbl>,
#   q38 <dbl>, q39 <dbl>, q40 <dbl>, q41 <dbl>, q42 <dbl>, q43 <dbl>, q44 <dbl>,
#   q45 <dbl>, q46 <dbl>, q47 <dbl>, q48 <dbl>, q49 <dbl>, q50 <dbl>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

While evaluating the answers of the students, the KR20 reliability coefficient, the item difficulty index, the percentage of correct answers, etc. were used. I want to calculate values. These are possible in the psych package. Instead of using this package, I can calculate values by coding students' answers as 1 (true) and 0 (false) according to the correct answer key. but as you mentioned, I couldn't do it because it's not numeric.

Comment: See my answer update. Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: one more request...output consist of 100 pcs 1x50 tibbles...is it possible to combine them into one tibble or data frame for analysind columns

Comment: use `unnest(data)`